# Xcode11 disable dark mode

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode11

Hi everyone I need information. I noticed that after installing xcode11 any new project I run this has enabled darkmode on the storyboard. is it possible to disable this function?

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, with the Storyboard open, go to the bottom left of the screen and look for "View as: |DeviceName|".
Tap it to expand the bottom window for the storyboard preview settings. You will see the middle setting is "Interface Style". Choose the empty one for Light and the filled one for Dark.

Heres a screenshot:
[image: change storyboard to lightmode]